# C Passing an int in a function?

Tags: c

I am getting incorrect results when passing a int in a function:

```
int recruit(int var1, int re_unit, char *char_buffer, int var2) {
 int run = 1;
 int int_buffer = 0;
 printf("Test1 %d\n", var1);
 printf("Test2 %d\n", var2);
 ...
}
void some_other_function(structs, struct1[]) {
 int var1 = 0;
 int var2 = 0;
 int re_unit = 0;
 char char_buffer[] = "What ever";

 //strucs[1].first = 50 this is done in a other section

 var1 = strucs1[1].first;
 var2 = strucs1[1].first;


 recruit(var1, re_unit, char_buffer, var2);
  // Ind the full verstion of the program this function is called 2 times:
  // The first time nothing is worng, how ever the second time, the result
  // is as explaned below


  //strucs[2].first = 50 // this is done in a other section
  var1 = struct1[2].first;
  var2 = struct1[2].first;

 recruit(var1, re_unit, char_buffer, var2);

}

int main(void) {
 ...
}
```

Now the results is that
 The first time
 Test1 prints: 2684032, and 
 Test2 prints: 50

The second time
 Test 1 prints: 2684032 and
 Test 2 prints: 50;

They should all print 50.

I have tested that the value of struct1[1].first is 50 before it's used in the function recruit.

Does any one know a reason why this could happen?

Comment: Please provide an **actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).**

Comment: Your variable names are frustrating.

Comment: `Duur[hurr].derp = 50`? **Really**?

Comment: He might be coding using another language than english.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized values in C's functions are not 0, they are just garbage whatever memory had at that particular moment..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("%i\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

That should demonstrate the idea...

Hopefully I interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: Well, I can't make sense of the question, but  //Duur[hurr].derp = 50 is commented our, so I think that the odd value is due to it never being initialized. So I thought that  Test1 prints: 2684032. lvl IS INITIALIZED, but then it is reinitialized to  lvl = Duur[hurr].derp which is NOT INITIALIZED, or at least we do not know what it's initialized to. The problem is clearly occuring inside that struct. At least I think Duur is a struct...

Comment: my problem with that is that both lvl variables are set to durr[hurr].depp. even if it's uninitialised, it's unlikely to be two values at the same time :-)

Comment: strucs[1].first (Duur[hurr].derp) is commented, because the code that initialized it is somewhere else.

Comment: That is a good point, this does seem strange. I really can't say much about this particular fragment of code, while it doesn't make sense, it should print Test1 == Test2, unless there is some magic affecting it. For all I know, there could be a #define macro making everything loopy... or anything

Answer (score 0):

Please change this statement `int recruit(int lvl, int re_unit, char *char_buffer, int u_lvl, int lvl2)` to `int recruit(int lvl, int re_unit, char *char_buffer, int lvl, int lvl2)`. You are observing an incorrect value due to uninitialized variables.

Comment: WTH? How is this going to fix an uninit variable problem when `u_lvl/lvl1` isn't even used ?

Comment: In the code segment pasted earlier, `lvl2` was the name of the variable being passed as well as the function parameter. Hence, to maintain a similar look and  feel, I recommended the renaming of `u_lvl` to `lvl` as this was the one which was being used to print inside the `recruit` function