# Not passing expected value in function

Tags: c

I have a function:

```
int somefunction(int a, int b, char *c, int d){}
```

Now this function is called in an other function which is in `main()`.

I call `somefunction(a, b, c, d);` and I have it print out `int a`, witch is declared as 50, before `somefunction()` is called. In the first call 50 is printed, all good and dandy, but the second call of `somefunction()` prints out 29549.
These function calls are inside some if statements, and even if the second place were `somefunction()` is called, is called first it's the same.

For testing all the input values have been set as the same, so its not the input.
All in put values is printed before calling `somefunction()`, and are as they should be. I have tried renaming all variables, functions, I tried to change all int's to float, and I tried moving the order of the variables in `somefunction()`. But noting changed. I have made prototypes as well, it's not that.

So does anyone have any idea of what could course this? The actual code is not here because I passed 2000 lines, and there would be a lot of irrelevant code in between. I realize it might be hard to help me, so I am only asking if anyone have experienced anything similar.

Comment: Please post real code rather than a description of code. It's much easier to understand and see the details which are problematic.

Comment: Well I tried yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794537/c-passing-an-int-in-a-function see if you can make any sence of it

Comment: I'm sorry but what you have there isn't real code. It's pseudo-C. There's a bunch of variables you're not using. Produce a minimal, compilable piece of code that reproduces your issue (and if your issue is a compile error, that's fine too).

Comment: I think some of us did try to help you in the post. Could you please re-post your function especially the initialization of structs array

Comment: You should post the actual code. Even if the whole thing is over 2000 lines, you only need to post the part of the code that's producing the problem.

Comment: Please give us a relevant SSCCE and we will definitely help you. It's not hard on your part. (http://sscce.org/)


  [1]: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Can you please confirm if the value of a before the second call to the function is indeed 50 by putting a print?

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings and debugging info (on Linux, with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I'm using a language with pointers and unsafe arrays, and crazy things start happening, then I have to soon suspect that I'm overwriting memory. There are many ways to do this: writing past the end of an array, using an uninitialized pointer, free()ing something that was never malloc()ed, etc.

If that's what's happening in your case, it's very hard to solve it without seeing the *precise* and *complete* code (trying to make a simplified example will often just make the problem go away as you either remove the erroneous code or rearrange memory so that something different and perhaps innocuous is being overwritten).

If you can't post a complete example that exhibits the bug, then you can start looking at likely culprits: a) all use of dynamic memory functions, b) all dereferencing of pointers.

About all I could glean from your other post was a) yup, that's the kind of code that's ripe for wild pointers and b) hmmmm, what's this:

```
char char_buffer[] = "What ever";
```

Hard to guess from code fragments, but usually the word "buffer" implies some biggish amount of space that's going to get reused more than once. You've named a character pointer "char_buffer", but it actually points to a string constant. So, for example, if you later tried to copy 11 characters worth of data to it, then you would overwrite something else (assuming the compiler/linker didn't store the constant in read-only memory for you).

Comment: @ Ron Burk. Yes you were right. The bug was a result of a strcpy that copied a string bigger than the char buffer into it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code to test your logic. Please find a small code below which functions fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunc(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Inside interface function: a: %d\t b: %d\n", a, b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
      int a = 35, b = 45;
      printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
     someFunc(a, b);
     a = 50; b = 75;
     printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
     someFunc(a, b);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick observation. The following parameters are not initialized       `Barrack[0].pikemen` `Barrack[0].men_at_arms` `Barrack[0].archers`    `Barrack[0].swords_men` `Barrack[0].crosbow` `Barrack[0].knights` Please check if this could be the source of your problem

Comment: No, that did nothing i'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please tell which lines of code you are facing the issue with?

Comment: Line 361 is where the function is called where the original problem was.

Comment: From your code `recruit_unit_function` can be called for both `pikemen` and `men_at_arms`. Are you sure that in both the cases it is called from the same point?